# Uneven increment in JQuery UI slide for dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that when using the JQuery UI slider for dates with a daily step it does not increment in exact steps of 1 day, but a number close to it.

How can I force the JQuery UI to increment by **exactly** 1 day when sliding the slider?

```
$('#sliderId').slider({
                       range: true,
                       min: minDate.unix(),
                       max: maxDate.unix(),
                       step: 1
                       })

// maxDate.unix() = 1600732800
// minDate.unix() = 1589500800
```

[image]
[image]

Please see the above two images on how the hour and minute changes by sliding the slider one step. The original minimum start value is 02 00 Fri May 2020, how can the step increment be ensured to generate 02 00 Sat May 2020 as the next value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix Time is the Seconds of Time since 01.01.1970. So to Increment by 1 Day you would need to Step the slider as much seconds as there are in one day. You have 60 Seconds each Minute, 60 Minutes each Hour, 24 Hours Each day. Thus 60x60x24 = 86400.

So you would need to set your Step to: 86400